# How can I debug my .NET Core unit tests using Visual Studio with WSL 2?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux, .net-5, wsl-2

With Visual Studio, I can debug my .NET Core applications running in Windows and WSL 2. For WSL 2, I use [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.Dot-Net-Core-Debugging-With-Wsl2). This is working fine. I can also debug my unit tests in Windows. This is working fine too. However, I do not know how how to debug my unit tests with Visual Studio running in WSL 2. I hope someone can help me and explain how I can debug not just my console apps and web apps in WSL 2, but also my unit tests. Please let me know.

Comment: Unit tests should be runtime and platform independent. What is reason to debug them in WSL?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski "should".... Maybe, in an ideal world. But that is just an extra reason to debug in WSL as there is a Linux only failure of a test and I am to one to find out what went wrong.

Comment: Then your tests are integration ones actually

Comment: You cannot know without seeing the code. Unit test failures can have many causes, including platform specific compiler bugs or bugs in the .NET runtime.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: To test the production code in multiple platforms.

Answer (score 18):

## Update 2022 Feb - VS 2022

Run on a win 10 dev machine

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

Reboot!

Run on the dev machine

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl --update
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
```

Run in your new wsl machine (ubuntu 22.04 or newer)

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt install dotnet6 -y
```

<strike>Run in your new wsl machine</strike> (Pre ubuntu 22.04 - now obsolete)

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb 
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install apt-transport-https git 
sudo apt update && sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0 -y
```

Add testenvironments.json to your solution root

```json
{
    "version": "1",
    "environments": [
        {
            "name": "Ubuntu",
            "type": "wsl",
            "wslDistribution": "Ubuntu"
        }
    ]
}
```

Visual Studio will show a new dropdown in the test explorer, select "Ubuntu", after built once using wsl tests can be run and debugged.

[image]

This setup does not depend on Docker. Winver shows "20h2"

## Old

Debugging tests isn't supported using ".NET Core Debugging with WSL 2" extension.

> This tooling does not support running tests in WSL2, but I do know our sister team has this on their backlog to enable!
> [.NET Core Debugging with WSL 2 - Q&A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.Dot-Net-Core-Debugging-With-Wsl2&ssr=false#qna)

Comment: For some reason it does not discover the tests :/ . but great answer I am sure I will somehow make it work. Perhaps the reason why tests are not discovered are because they are outside the solution root directory and they are references.

Comment: It does not discover me neither. (and my tests are not outside the solution root). using VS 2022 17.7.6, current latest

Comment: Tests get discovered after the project has been built after "Ubuntu" was selected.... if that is not working with your setup you could try to test your wsl installation with a project that is known to work, e.g. https://github.com/Codeuctivity/ImageSharp.Compare/blob/main/testenvironments.json

Comment: The setup changed in case of .net 8 again. In case of .net 8 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77572125/1258111

Answer (score 6):

Update: The feature is available from within Visual Studio 2022. It enables you to debug tests both in WSL 2 and Docker.

A howto is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/remote-testing?view=vs-2022